# How to create objects for this issue?

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, derived-class

First of all I would like to say I am beginner and I did some research on this issue

I created five classes `superbase`, `base` and 3 derived:

```
class superbase
{


    QList<base*> listofbase;  //Composition relation between super base and base

    // some other attributes 

    public:

    superbase(); // or other overloaded constructor

};

class base
{
    int i;

    public:

    base();

};

class derived1 : // Which inheritance should be used with base
{
    int j;

    public:

    derived1();   // or other overloaded constructor

};

class derived2 : // Which inheritance should be used with base
{
    int k;

    public:

    derived2();   // or other overloaded constructor

};

class derived3: // Which inheritance should be used with base
{
    int l;

    public:

    derived3();   // or other overloaded constructor

};
```

- `superbase` and `base` have composition relation
- `derived1`, `derived2`, `derived3` inherit only from `base` **not `superbase`**
- There are no methods the classes
- I also tried virtual inheritance, but I am not getting it properly, as everywhere people mention about a "diamond problem" but this is not the same.

My Task

- I am supposed to create multiple objects of `base` class as private attribute of `superbase` class( `QList< base* > listofbase;` ). Each object of base class can contain multiple objects of derived classes (`derived1`, `derived2` or `derived3`).

Questions:

1. How can I create objects for the derived class so that all derived class **share only one single copy of base class object**  ?
2. Which inheritance must be used in derived classes to generate only single copy of base object?

Comment: Why is `superbase` involved here? You could remove it entirely and still have the same question.

Comment: Also, does your task require that you use *inheritance*? It does not seem like the right approach.

Comment: Well dis problem is actually implementation of one class diagram .. lets say name of superbase is other random name A .. here between class A and base , there is composition relation 1-->1..*

That is why superbase(A) have QList od base pointers as private attribute. So i can not omit superbase(A) class

Comment: Yes I am required to use inheritance because in that class diagram derived1, derived2 and derived3 are derived from class base ... But i am not sure which inheritance and how to use, to make single copy of base class object.

Comment: I do not think that this is possible. Did someone tell you that it was?

Answer (score -1):

Use static factory and protected constructor to achieve that in Base class.

Comment: ok I will go through from static factory ... But which inheritance should be used ?????

As per my knowledge, lets say m using static factory and at time of creating first derived i m creating one object of base ... But while creating other derived objects how to use dat one and only base class created object as to maintain single copy .... should i use refernce for that base class object or what ????

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I don't see how that satisfies the requirement.

Comment: @user2086832 What's the original requirement ? Maybe some mis-understanding for it

Comment: class base { protected: base(); public: static base* getBaseObject(); };  clase derivedx:public base{ };

Comment: @ shuiyu , @ Beta .. My requirement is simple .... Multiple derived class objects and all those objects share one and only one base class object .....

@ Adnan Akbar : Thank you .. I can see some hope with this code but picture is still unclear .. Looking upon ur code , does it mean first i have to create base object separately then each derived class object wont be able to call base constructor and will simply get the address of existing base class copy .... is it correct ?

Comment: yup that is correct. Since you will not be able to create object of base class from outside derived class it will be required to use factory method to get an object for it. Set a private field for base class pointer in derived class.

Comment: Also since all the derived classes are also base you will have to make sure in your code that when ever you ask for base it is from the factory method or create some function like getSharedBase().

Comment: **This does not satisfy the requirement.** Each instance `derivedx` will have its own `base` members (such as `i`, as you can verify). This solution simply allows them to have pointers to *another* instance of `base`.

Comment: @Beta I agree with alone language constructs this can not be strictly implemented. A little bit of code agreement has to be introduced.

Comment: @Beta Thngs r confusing... To avoid this situation which kind of inheritance we should use with base (If base is static factory class) ...???

Comment: well there is one solution to have an error in case if the wrong object is recieved where you are going to use the shared base object. But no inheratance is the answer to have that single base object:).